# Heroku does not choose the right web server

Tags: heroku, unicorn

I wanted to use unicorn in my rails app hosted in heroku. I followed heroku 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn. But it seems like heroku choose 'thin' web server instead of 'unicorn'. Below is the screen shoot of my heroku dashboard.

[image]

From this daskboard I am sure that heroku is aware of my Procfile, however when I run

```
heroku ps logs --app vamos-test
```

I ve got the following logs

```
 === run: one-off dyno
 run.1: up for 5m: `bash`

 === web: `bundle exec thin start -p $PORT`
 web.1: created for 30s
```

From this logs I assumed that 'thin' is my app server.

I also tried a few command to fixed the problems:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 --app vamos-test 
heroku ps:restart --app vamos-test
```

But I still get the same log as above.

**This is my config/unicorn.rb file**

```
 #config/unicorn.rb
 worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
 timeout 15
 preload_app true

 before_fork do |server, worker|
   Signal.trap 'TERM' do
     puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
   Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
 end

 defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
 end

 after_fork do |server, worker|
   Signal.trap 'TERM' do
     puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
   end

   defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
 end
```

**Here my Procfile**

```
#config/unicorn.rb
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

and unicorn gem is correctly included in Gemfile.

Do I miss something ? Please help

Comment: Weird.   What happens when you remove `thin` from your Gemfile?  And the # line from your Procfile?  Also, I guess you didn't really run `heroku ps logs` right?  That's not a valid command?

Comment: @JonMountjoy I don't have thin in my gem file.

Comment: Channa, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Walksalong not yet. any idea about this ?